# Health bar three js javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have a health bar that used to work in r118.1 but no longer does after upgrading to r127 im unsure of what i need to change though to get it back working? there is an error with the shader in r127 heres the code:

code:

```
import * as THREE from './three/build/three.module.js';

import {entity} from './entity.js';
import {math} from './math.js';


export const health_bar = (() => {
  const _VS = `
varying vec2 vUV;
void main() {
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
  vUV = uv;
}
`;

  const _PS = `
uniform vec3 colour;
uniform float health;
varying vec2 vUV;
out vec4 out_FragColor;
void main() {
  out_FragColor = vec4(mix(colour, vec3(0.0), step(health, vUV.y)), 1.0);
}
`;

class HealthBar extends entity.Component {
  constructor(params) {
    super();
    this._params = params;
    this._Initialize();
  }

  _Initialize() {
    const uniforms = {
      colour: {
        value: new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 ),
      },
      health: {
        value: 1.0,
      },
    };
    this._material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
       uniforms: uniforms,
      vertexShader: _VS,
      fragmentShader: _PS,
      blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
      transparent: true,
      depthTest: false,
      depthWrite: false,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });

    this._geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    this._bar = new THREE.Mesh(this._geometry, this._material);
    this._bar.frustumCulled = false;
    this._bar.scale.set(2, 0.125, 1);

    this._realHealth = 1.0;
    this._animHealth = 1.0;

    this._params.parent.add(this._bar);
    this._GenerateBuffers();
  }

  InitComponent() {
    this._RegisterHandler('health.update', (m) => { this._OnHealth(m); });
  }

  _OnHealth(msg) {
    const healthPercent = (msg.health / msg.maxHealth);
    
    this._realHealth = healthPercent;
  }

  Update(timeElapsed) {
    const t = 1.0 - Math.pow(0.001, timeElapsed);

    this._animHealth = math.lerp(t, this._animHealth, this._realHealth);

    const _R = new THREE.Color(1.0, 0, 0);
    const _G = new THREE.Color(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    const c = _R.clone();
    c.lerpHSL(_G, this._animHealth);

    this._material.uniforms.health.value = this._animHealth;
    this._material.uniforms.colour.value = c;
    this._bar.position.copy(this._parent._position);
    this._bar.position.y += 8.0;
    this._bar.quaternion.copy(this._params.camera.quaternion);
  }

  _GenerateBuffers() {
    const indices = [];
    const positions = [];
    const uvs = [];

    const square = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0];

    indices.push(...square);

    const p1 = new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, 0);
    const p2 = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 0);
    const p3 = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0);
    const p4 = new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, 0);

    uvs.push(0.0, 0.0);
    uvs.push(1.0, 0.0);
    uvs.push(1.0, 1.0);
    uvs.push(0.0, 1.0);

    positions.push(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
    positions.push(p2.x, p2.y, p2.z);
    positions.push(p3.x, p3.y, p3.z);
    positions.push(p4.x, p4.y, p4.z);

    this._geometry.setAttribute(
        'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
    this._geometry.setAttribute(
        'uv', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
    this._geometry.setIndex(
        new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint32Array(indices), 1));

    this._geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
  }
};

  return {
    HealthBar: HealthBar,
  };
})();
```

and here is the shader error:

> THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog
> invalid shaders  THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
> ERROR: 0:3: 'pc_fragColor' : must explicitly specify all locations
> when using multiple fragment outputs ERROR: 0:134: 'out_FragColor' :
> must explicitly specify all locations when using multiple fragment
> outputs 1: #version 300 es 2: #define varying in 3: out highp vec4
> pc_fragColor; 4: #define gl_FragColor pc_fragColor 5: #define
> gl_FragDepthEXT gl_FragDepth 6: #define texture2D texture 7: #define
> textureCube texture 8: #define texture2DProj textureProj 9: #define
> texture2DLodEXT textureLod 10: #define texture2DProjLodEXT
> textureProjLod 11: #define textureCubeLodEXT textureLod 12: #define
> texture2DGradEXT textureGrad 13: #define texture2DProjGradEXT
> textureProjGrad 14: #define textureCubeGradEXT textureGrad 15:
> precision highp float; 16: precision highp int; 17: #define
> HIGH_PRECISION 18: #define SHADER_NAME ShaderMaterial 19: #define
> GAMMA_FACTOR 2 20: #define DOUBLE_SIDED 21: #define USE_SHADOWMAP 22:
> #define SHADOWMAP_TYPE_PCF_SOFT 23: uniform mat4 viewMatrix; 24: uniform vec3 cameraPosition; 25: uniform bool isOrthographic; 26:
> #define TONE_MAPPING 27: #ifndef saturate 28: #define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 ) 29: #endif 30: uniform float toneMappingExposure;
> 31: vec3 LinearToneMapping( vec3 color ) { 32:    return
> toneMappingExposure * color; 33: } 34: vec3 ReinhardToneMapping( vec3
> color ) { 35:     color *= toneMappingExposure; 36:   return saturate(
> color / ( vec3( 1.0 ) + color ) ); 37: } 38: vec3
> OptimizedCineonToneMapping( vec3 color ) { 39:    color *=
> toneMappingExposure; 40:  color = max( vec3( 0.0 ), color - 0.004 );
> 41:   return pow( ( color * ( 6.2 * color + 0.5 ) ) / ( color * ( 6.2 *
> color + 1.7 ) + 0.06 ), vec3( 2.2 ) ); 42: } 43: vec3 RRTAndODTFit(
> vec3 v ) { 44:    vec3 a = v * ( v + 0.0245786 ) - 0.000090537; 45:
> vec3 b = v * ( 0.983729 * v + 0.4329510 ) + 0.238081; 46:   return a /
> b; 47: } 48: vec3 ACESFilmicToneMapping( vec3 color ) { 49:   const
> mat3 ACESInputMat = mat3( 50:         vec3( 0.59719, 0.07600, 0.02840
> ),        vec3( 0.35458, 0.90834, 0.13383 ), 51:      vec3( 0.04823, 0.01566,
> 0.83777 ) 52:     ); 53:  const mat3 ACESOutputMat = mat3( 54:        vec3(  1.60475, -0.10208, -0.00327 ),       vec3( -0.53108,  1.10813, -0.07276 ), 55:       vec3( -0.07367, -0.00605,  1.07602 ) 56:    ); 57:  color *=
> toneMappingExposure / 0.6; 58:    color = ACESInputMat * color; 59:
> color = RRTAndODTFit( color ); 60:  color = ACESOutputMat * color;
> 61:   return saturate( color ); 62: } 63: vec3 CustomToneMapping( vec3
> color ) { return color; } 64: vec3 toneMapping( vec3 color ) { return
> LinearToneMapping( color ); } 65:  66: vec4 LinearToLinear( in vec4
> value ) { 67:     return value; 68: } 69: vec4 GammaToLinear( in vec4
> value, in float gammaFactor ) { 70:   return vec4( pow( value.rgb,
> vec3( gammaFactor ) ), value.a ); 71: } 72: vec4 LinearToGamma( in
> vec4 value, in float gammaFactor ) { 73:  return vec4( pow( value.rgb,
> vec3( 1.0 / gammaFactor ) ), value.a ); 74: } 75: vec4 sRGBToLinear(
> in vec4 value ) { 76:     return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb * 0.9478672986
>
> - vec3( 0.0521327014 ), vec3( 2.4 ) ), value.rgb * 0.0773993808, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.04045 ) ) ) ), value.a ); 77: } 78:
>   vec4 LinearTosRGB( in vec4 value ) { 79:  return vec4( mix( pow(
>   value.rgb, vec3( 0.41666 ) ) * 1.055 - vec3( 0.055 ), value.rgb *
>   12.92, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.0031308 ) ) ) ), value.a ); 80: } 81: vec4 RGBEToLinear( in vec4 value ) { 82:     return
>   vec4( value.rgb * exp2( value.a * 255.0 - 128.0 ), 1.0 ); 83: } 84:
>   vec4 LinearToRGBE( in vec4 value ) { 85:  float maxComponent = max(
>   max( value.r, value.g ), value.b ); 86:   float fExp = clamp( ceil(
>   log2( maxComponent ) ), -128.0, 127.0 ); 87:  return vec4( value.rgb /
>   exp2( fExp ), ( fExp + 128.0 ) / 255.0 ); 88: } 89: vec4 RGBMToLinear(
>   in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) { 90:  return vec4( value.rgb *
>   value.a * maxRange, 1.0 ); 91: } 92: vec4 LinearToRGBM( in vec4 value,
>   in float maxRange ) { 93:     float maxRGB = max( value.r, max( value.g,
>   value.b ) ); 94:  float M = clamp( maxRGB / maxRange, 0.0, 1.0 ); 95:
>   M = ceil( M * 255.0 ) / 255.0; 96:  return vec4( value.rgb / ( M *
>   maxRange ), M ); 97: } 98: vec4 RGBDToLinear( in vec4 value, in float
>   maxRange ) { 99:  return vec4( value.rgb * ( ( maxRange / 255.0 ) /
>   value.a ), 1.0 ); 100: } 101: vec4 LinearToRGBD( in vec4 value, in
>   float maxRange ) { 102:   float maxRGB = max( value.r, max( value.g,
>   value.b ) ); 103:     float D = max( maxRange / maxRGB, 1.0 ); 104:   D =
>   clamp( floor( D ) / 255.0, 0.0, 1.0 ); 105:   return vec4( value.rgb *
>   ( D * ( 255.0 / maxRange ) ), D ); 106: } 107: const mat3 cLogLuvM =
>   mat3( 0.2209, 0.3390, 0.4184, 0.1138, 0.6780, 0.7319, 0.0102, 0.1130,
>   0.2969 ); 108: vec4 LinearToLogLuv( in vec4 value ) { 109:    vec3 Xp_Y_XYZp = cLogLuvM * value.rgb; 110:     Xp_Y_XYZp = max( Xp_Y_XYZp,
>   vec3( 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6 ) ); 111:  vec4 vResult; 112:  vResult.xy =
>   Xp_Y_XYZp.xy / Xp_Y_XYZp.z; 113:  float Le = 2.0 * log2(Xp_Y_XYZp.y) +
>   127.0; 114:   vResult.w = fract( Le ); 115:   vResult.z = ( Le - ( floor( vResult.w * 255.0 ) ) / 255.0 ) / 255.0; 116:   return vResult;
>   117: } 118: const mat3 cLogLuvInverseM = mat3( 6.0014, -2.7008,
>   -1.7996, -1.3320, 3.1029, -5.7721, 0.3008, -1.0882, 5.6268 ); 119: vec4 LogLuvToLinear( in vec4 value ) { 120:    float Le = value.z *
>   255.0 + value.w; 121:     vec3 Xp_Y_XYZp; 122:    Xp_Y_XYZp.y = exp2( ( Le - 127.0 ) / 2.0 ); 123:    Xp_Y_XYZp.z = Xp_Y_XYZp.y / value.y; 124:   Xp_Y_XYZp.x = value.x * Xp_Y_XYZp.z; 125:   vec3 vRGB =
>   cLogLuvInverseM * Xp_Y_XYZp.rgb; 126:     return vec4( max( vRGB, 0.0 ),
>   1.0 ); 127: } 128: vec4 linearToOutputTexel( vec4 value ) { return LinearTosRGB( value ); } 129:  130:  131: uniform vec3 colour; 132:
>   uniform float health; 133: varying vec2 vUV; 134: out vec4
>   out_FragColor; 135: void main() { 136:   out_FragColor =
>   vec4(mix(colour, vec3(0.0), step(health, vUV.y)), 1.0); 137: } 138:
>   Mt.forEach.n. @ eruda:27 WebGLProgram @
>   three.module.js:17234 acquireProgram @ three.module.js:17700
>   getProgram @ three.module.js:24565 setProgram @ three.module.js:24723
>   WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect @ three.module.js:23926 renderObject
>   @ three.module.js:24504 renderObjects @ three.module.js:24477
>   WebGLRenderer.render @ three.module.js:24257 (anonymous) @
>   main.js:1377 256WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not
>   valid

thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with `out vec4 out_FragColor;`.

```glsl
out vec4 out_FragColor;
void main() {
  out_FragColor = vec4(mix(colour, vec3(0.0), step(health, vUV.y)), 1.0);
}
```

Why don't you just use the default `gl_FragColor`? When using a `ShaderMaterial`, Three.js automatically takes care of the fragment output for you, so you don't have to override it.

```glsl
// out vec4 out_FragColor; <-Remove this line
void main() {
  gl_FragColor= vec4(mix(colour, vec3(0.0), step(health, vUV.y)), 1.0);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply ill try this today and mark as correct if it works you haven't let me down yet tho you have answered a few of my questions here and elsewhere :) thank you

Comment: sadly didnt work

Comment: You’re gonna have to create a working demo for others to be able to help you. Maybe through a code snippet or jsfiddle.net

Comment: managed to fix the issue

Comment: const _PS = `
uniform vec3 colour;
uniform float health;

varying vec2 vUV;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(colour, vec3(0.0), step(health, vUV.y)), 1.0);;
   }